# Can I have both 2.79 and 2.8 on my system? Will one interfere with the other?

Tags: installation

I have Blender 2.79 on my Windows 7 system.

I want to install 2.8, but I'm completing some courses which use 2.79.

If I install 2.8, will it automatically replace 2.79?

Will they interfere with one another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install multiple versions of Blender alongside without them interfering.

They will each have their own Preferences and scripts folder. On windows, there will be a folder for each version.

[image: version files]

You can also use a Blender version without "installing" it by downloading the portable version.

[image]

Comment: I have 2.79 version and when i install 2.83 version it got overlapped now only i have 2.83. how to have both version. But the folder of 2.79 and 2.83 are in the blender foundation. When click on desktop exe it opens 2.83 and not separate version seen. Before i used to use zip version and the folder is created.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you don't save the files in 2.8, these files cannot be opened with 2.79.